# Symfony2 - Trying to understand FOSUserBundle Registration confirmation

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to Symfony and I pretty much now understand the basics and now I am diving into Events and Events Listeners.

I understand that when a user registers via [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) there are three Events that get dispatched inside `registerAction()`

1. REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE
2. REGISTRATION_SUCCESS
3. REGISTRATION_COMPLETED

This is the `registerAction` code

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Now inside the `config.yml` we can setup the configuration so the user is required to confirm their email address before their account gets activated and this is where I get lost

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
```

I am looking at [EmailConfirmationListener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailConfirmationListener.php#L12) which listens to the `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` and inside this code I am finding nothing that tells me how it is reading the `confirmation` in `config.yml`

I will really appreciate if someone can explain to me how this listener is triggered based on `confirmation` `enabled` status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class) explains

> In order to load service configuration, you have to create a
>   Dependency Injection (DI) Extension for your bundle

I did a search in the repository and, as [you can see](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=email_confirmation.xml), the `FOSUserExtension.php` file loads a service file which contains the listener declaration.